# Problem with Java semaphores (tryAcquire)

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, semaphore

I'm trying to produce the AAB AAB sequence with this code:

```
private static Semaphore semA = new Semaphore(2);
private static Semaphore semB = new Semaphore(0);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        new P1A().start();
        new P2B().start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

static class P1A extends Thread{
    
    public void run() {
        try {
            semA.acquire();
            System.out.print("A");
            if(!semA.tryAcquire()) {
                semB.release();
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

static class P2B extends Thread{
    
    public void run() {
        try {
            semB.acquire();
            System.out.print("B ");
            semA.release(2);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In this code the final result is "A".

From what I know tryAcquire () should immediately return true or false as the case may be, instead it seems to respond late.
How can we solve this problem?

Comment: It would be helpful to see how `semA` and `semB` were constructed (initial permits).  And what are your actual results?

Comment: I have updated the question. I apologize for not entering this information earlier.

Comment: One issue with your test setup is you create new threads on every iteration of the main loop - this means as I'll explain `P2B` is blocked and then the main creates new threads and `P2A` becomes blocked and **the 2nd `P2B`** is also blocked...`P2B` becomes blocked on the first iteration because `P2A` acquired `semA` twice and does not release `semB` which is initially 0 permits.  So your test setup needs work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is primarily an explanation of your issue and an approach of analysis - but I did see what you are attempting and added a simple fix.

It might be best to use a table as you walk through the logic.  Note that the order of execution of `P1A` and `P2B` may vary and so this is one sequence - but I'm certain all sequences lead to the same outcome described:

```
|     P1A     | semA |     P2B     | semB | Output |
| ----------- | ---- | ----------- | ---- | ------ |
| [1] started |      |             |      |        |
|             |   2  |             |   0  |        |
| [1] acq  A  |   1  |             |   0  |        |
|             |      |             |      |    A   |
| [1] acqt A  |   0  |             |   0  |        |
|             |      | [1] started |   0  |        |
|             |   0  | [1] blocked |   0  |        |
| [1] end     |   0  |             |   0  |        |
| [2] started |   0  |             |   0  |        |
| [2] blocked |   0  |             |      |        |
|             |   0  | [2] started |   0  |        |
|             |   0  | [2] blocked |   0  |        |
```

ad infinitum.

It seems starting new threads on each iteration only complicates the results - as opposed to having each threads loop forever on its own.

Since `semA` is initialized with 2 permits, the `tryAcquire` will be successful (true) and so the `!tryAcquire` is false.

### Update P1A

And now that I see what you are attempting, I think the following is more direct to your approach.  Just have `P1A` do this (leave `P2B` as is):

```
public void run() {
        if (semA.tryAcquire()) {
           System.out.print("A");
        } else {
            semB.release();
        }
}
```

With your regard to your main loop - I can't say it's wrong *except* it does not wait for the threads to complete (join) which can only lead to confusing results.  So either `join` both threads (instead of sleep) or move the forever loops into the threads.